# Javascript: Parse string array into object with custom key names and values

Tags: javascript, arrays, parsing, object

So I have a string which contains a list of custom http headers that is in the following format:

```
var headers = "Referer=SomeValue|User-Agent=SomeUserAgent";
```

I split that up using the pipe as a delimiter:

```
var splitHeaders = headers.split("|");
```

I'm left with an array which I can loop through, and I'm trying to convert that string array into an object. This is what I have so far:

```
var customHeaders = {};
for (var i in splitHeaders) {
    var data = splitHeaders[i].split("=");
    customHeaders[data[0]] = data[1];
}
```

What I'm essentially trying to create is an object called customHeaders to hold values like:

```
customHeaders = {
    "Referer":"https://someurl.com/",
    "User-Agent":"Some Browser"
};
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track. Use a more standard form of the for loop using the length of the `splitHeaders` as a limiter:

```
for (var i = 0; i < splitHeaders.length; i++) {
```

Working example:

```js
var headers = "Referer=SomeValue|User-Agent=SomeUserAgent";
var splitHeaders = headers.split('|');
var customHeaders = {};

for (var i = 0; i < splitHeaders.length; i++) {
  var data = splitHeaders[i].split("=");
  customHeaders[data[0]] = data[1];
}

console.log(customHeaders);
```

---

There are also other methods you can use that allow you to convert an array of items into an object, using such as [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=b).

```js
var headers = "Referer=SomeValue|User-Agent=SomeUserAgent";

headers = headers
  .split('|')
  .reduce(function(obj, val) {
    var split = val.split('=');
    obj[split[0]] = split[1];
    return obj;
  }, {});

console.log(headers);
```

Comment: Also thank you for the reduce function reference, I'm still learning JS, this will help!